# How to disable generic inheritance for the super class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, java-8

I have a class `Foo` which has this instance attribute : an object constructed from a class called `SuperClass`. This `SuperClass` is the parent of another class, say... `SubClass`.

In fact, I'm going to be more precise. `Foo`'s attribute can be anything (generics) but this "anything" has to extend from `SuperClass`. You can take a look at the code below (it's the translation of what I'm saying).

```
class Foo<K extends SuperClass> {
   K attr;
}
```

In fact, `K` must be a `SubClass` object. NOT DIRECTLY a `SuperClass` one.

But I tried, to test, to create a `Foo` object with `K` = `SuperClass`... and it works... **It's the problem.**

Well, do you know how to avoid the possibility to create a `Foo` object using a `SuperClass` instead of one child please ?

Comment: I think that handling an `Exception` using `instanceOf` could be correct, but is there another means ?

Comment: Usually in OO a base class or interface defines what is available, and implementing classes fill in the behavior; see the Liskov substiution principle at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle Hence it does not make much sense to me to only allow derived classes, but exclude their base. I guess you could add another class in the hierarchy for exactly that purpose. But maybe try to explain what you are really trying to do and why you cannot accept a SuperClass.

Comment: Simple solution: `class Foo { SubClass attr; }`. Advanced solution: `class Foo<K extends SubClass> { K attr; }`. Use only the advanced solution if there’s a reason why the simple solution cannot fulfil your requirements.

Comment: Why don't you want `K` to be a `SuperClass`? It is hard to imagine what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Another simple solution: declare SuperClass abstract. It will make sure that no objects of that class can exist, so any object assigned to attr will belong to some subclass of SuperClass.

Comment: Generic code is, as the name suggests, supposed to be *generic*, not special cased…

Answer (score 0):

With generics, if you use:

```
K extends SuperClass
```

Means that SuperClass type and its subclasses are acceptable, thus your program is accepting the SuperClass.

If you want to accept only SubClass and its subclasses then use:

```
K extends SubClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `SuperClass` abstract or create an `Interface`.